# Label Declutter Circles with declut

Tags: canvas, openlayers

I'm using openLayers to display thousands of Circles over a map.  However when displaying all of the points it becomes a little overwhelming to the eye.  To help with this I added the declutter option in the vector Layer:

```
const allPointLayer = new VectorLayer({
            source: pointSource,
            visibility: true,
            style: scanLocationStyle,
            extent: this.extent,
            declutter: true,
        });
```

This was somewhat helpful as it would dynamically change the displayed circles that were being rendered.

But now I would like to add some text to circles to represent how many circles there are being "summarized"

I did find there are DeclutterGroups in the ol/render/canvas module **http://webmail.rgurs.org/openlayers/apidoc/module-ol_render_canvas.html#~DeclutterGroup**, but no apparent way to edit the text for that group or to find the size of the array.  Here is the other relavent code snippets:

```
map = new Map({
            target: "map",
            view: new View({
                center: getCenter(this.extent),
                zoom: 15,
            }),
        });
const pointSource = new VectorSource({

            features: Collection,
            format: new GeoJSON(),
            style: scanLocationStyle,

        });
const style = new Style({
            image: circleStyle,
        });
        const allPointLayer = new VectorLayer({
            source: pointSource,
            visibility: true,
            style: style,
            extent: this.extent,
            declutter: true,
        });
```

I've added some images to help.

Thanks for the help!
[Decluttered Circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgXoO.png)

[Non cluttered circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJPnY.png)

Comment: Have you considered using a cluster source instead of declutter? https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Comment: No! I have not considered this.  But after a quick look, it looks to be exactly what I want.  Thanks Mike!